# Highcharts - Customizing legend for treemap

Tags: highcharts

I am currently creating a treemap using highcharts to display my data. I am attempting to customize the legend of my graph in order to show only the `parents` name and color in the legend.

For example, these are the parent id names in my data object

```
{
            id: 'low',
            color: "#0D6302"
        }, {
            id: 'med-low',
            color: "#0B7070"
        }, {
            id: 'med',
            color: '#DC9603'
        }, {
                id: 'med-high',
            color: '#DD5F0C'
        }, {
           id: 'high',
           color: "#C50710"
        }
```

I would like to only display in my legend: `green "low", blue "med-low", yellow "med", orange "med-high and red "high"`

Here is a photo of my current legend

[image]

I do not want to show "retail, online, in store, e-commernece, clothing, appointments and street vendors".

I've attempted this by using `showInLegend: true` and `legendType: "point"` in my series.

here is a link to a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/bahsm5t1/13/

Answer (score 1):

You can hide those legend points using below custom code which get access to them using the load callback.

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load(){
            let chart = this;
            
            chart.legend.allItems.forEach(item => {
                if(item.parent) {
                    item.legendGroup.hide();
                }
            })
        }
    }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uknf8xws/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load